# Randomly fill in a table of 25 values, that come from a set of 30 values?

Tags: excel

I want to make a series of tables that each contain 25 values, that come from a set of 30 values. How can I quickly, and randomly, produce these tables? I'm wondering if there is a way in excel, or will I need to program something, myself?  If so, which language would be the easiest (Python, C, Java)?

Edit: The 25 values would include no repeats.  In other words, I'm looking for random combinations (30C25) of the values.

Comment: Do these 25 values have to be different? (no repetition allowed?)

Comment: Yes, that would be desired.

Comment: In this case, I think you should use some programming. A UDF with VBA is an excellent an easy option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can eventually add the following custom User-Defined function and then use it as an array formula. Add the code to code module Module1:

```
Public Function RandUnique(src As Range) As Variant
    Dim v As Variant: v = src
    Randomize
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, temp As Variant
    For i = 1 To src.Rows.count
        j = 1 + Int(Rnd * src.Rows.count)
        temp = v(i, 1): v(i, 1) = v(j, 1): v(j, 1) = temp
    Next
    RandUnique = v
End Function
```

Once you have added this UDF,

```
Select the destination range, enter in the formula bar the following formula

=RandUnique($A$1:$A$30)     ' <~~ set it to your source range of 30 values

Then press Ctrl+Shift+Enter
```

Please note that the randomization procedure used is rather basic, so that not all the combinations have really equal probability, but it is fair enough, unless you are using it for some deep statistical analysis, in which case you might need a perfect randomizer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your assistance--this worked quite well, and your instructions were easy to follow.  I appreciate the time you took to assist me in figuring out my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Name a list of your thirty values in Excel in rows greater than 25 (say `List30`), then in A1 copied down to A25 and all copied across to suit:

```
=INDEX(List30,RANDBETWEEN(1,30))
```

To exclude repetitions (so not random choices) you might enter your list in A1:A30 and in B1 copied down to suit:

```
=RAND()
```

then sort A:B on ColumnB and copy A1:A25 to paste say to D1. This way only one set is generated at a time (the sort/copy/paste would have to be repeated after each paste).

Comment: Thank you so much!  Is there a way to avoid repeated random entries where I'm just getting random combinations of the 30 values? (30C25)?

Comment: You can combine the above with some VBA from http://www.cpearson.com/excel/randomnumbers.aspx. See the section part-way down the page called "Getting An Array Of Unique, Non-Duplicated Values."

Answer (score 0):

Here is an interesting way that requires no VBA nor any manual sorting.

- Enter your source list in the range A1:A30.
- In cell B1 enter this formula:

  `=CHOOSE(RANDBETWEEN(1,7),7,11,13,17,19,23,29)`
- In the range C1:C30 enter this formula:

  `=INDEX(A$1:A$30,MOD(ROWS(A$1:J1)*B$1,30))`
- In cell D1 enter this formula:

  `=RANDBETWEEN(1,30)`
- Now select any 25 contiguous vertical and empty cells and enter this formula:

  `=INDEX($C$1:$C$30,MOD(D$1+ROWS($A$1:$J1),30)+1)`

Now copy the 25 cells and paste as values somewhere for your 1st table. Press F9 on the keyboard to get a fresh 25; copy and paste as values somewhere for your 2nd table. Press F9 on the keyboard to get a fresh 25; copy and paste as values somewhere for your 3rd table. Keep repeating for as many tables as you need.

.

Please note that while this will look very random (with no repeats) it is not random at all. It's a complex interference pattern that will appear completely random unless you are the [Rain Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rain_Man).

Comment: Thank you very much.  For the purposes of my project, it is not necessary to be truly random, as much as the values needs to appear random, so this will be more than sufficient.  Thank you very much for your time and assistance.