# How can you put words from a list but in a random order?

Tags: vba, excel, random, shuffle

I have a list of 10 words on sheet2 and I need to create a button that puts 3 randomly selected words from this list onto another sheet. This needs to be repeated 10 times.
i.e. I need to click the button and it comes up with something like;
randomword randomword randomword
randomword randomword randomword
.....etc until this is done 10 times.

I have this so far but instead of the remaining 9 rows being randomized too, they are the same words as in the first row, can anyone help please?

```
For i = 1 To 10     'puts the list of 10 negative words into a list
myList(i) = Sheet2.Cells(i + 2, 1)
Next

Randomize

For i = 10 To 2 Step -1   'randomises the words in the list
    r = Int((i - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1)
    temp = myList(i): myList(i) = myList(r): myList(r) = temp
    Next i


For k = 1 To 10
    For i = 1 To 3
    Sheet3.Cells(k + 1, i + 1) = myList(i)
    Next i
Next k
```

Comment: This should be helpful as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33464262/randomly-fill-in-a-table-of-25-values-that-come-from-a-set-of-30-values

Comment: thank you but it doesn't help me (i am a complete noobie to VBA)! I can make it so 3 words from the list of 10 are randomly selected and put into a row but i cant seem to make this randomisation happen across 10 rows

Comment: Let me understand, are you talking about your code or the one I indicated? In your code the reason of the repetition is obvious btw.

Comment: You are putting the first 3 elements of the list in all the rows, but the list is the same, that is why all the rows are the same. To fix it, you should shuffle your list again once you go to a new row. Put the shuffling code in a separate routine and call it for every new row.